# Setting Up Flow in An Existing Project

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype, typechecking

Am running Ubuntu 16.04.
I am setting up [Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/) as per the instructions in the link, however, on the next page ([usage](https://flow.org/en/docs/usage/)), where we are directed to run the command:

`flow init`

I get the error:

`No command found...`

Which makes sense as `flow` was not installed globally, but as a dev-dependency within the existing project directory. They also recommend & I quote:

`Flow works best when installed per-project with explicit versioning rather than globally.`

So, my question is, am I missing a step in the installation of `flow`, which is causing the error? Or should I go ahead & `yarn add flow` globally.

Flow Installation Instructions:
https://flow.org/en/docs/install/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yarn will only install globally if you run `# yarn global <add/bin/ls/remove/upgrade> [--prefix]`. Using `$ yarn add --dev flow-bin` as the documentation states will be sufficient. Then, you should run `$ yarn run flow`.

The full instructions are [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/), and you can follow it with no problems.

You can also install it using npm instead of yarn:

`$ npm install --save flow-bin`

#### Edit

To get the `flow init` command to work you have to install Flow CLI globally, as the local flow binary won't be in your $PATH environment variable. The command is almost the same:

`# npm install --global flow-bin`

Alternatively you can execute the binary from within your local path. Something like: `$ ./node_modules/.bin/flow init`

Comment: I have done all of these steps, its at the next step when I initialise it that I get the error

Comment: Upon installing a package as a dev dependency, the binary will not be in PATH, and should be called from "node_modules/.bin/". Either call `flow` from there or install it globally as well.

Comment: You can install flow-cli with the same command, as global: `# npm install --global flow-bin`. The cli commands can be get with `$ flow --help`